# Getting ~ to expand in .hgrc on Windows

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

Is it possible to get the following to work?

```
[ui]
ssh = ~\bin\ssh -i ~\.ssh\my_key
```

Using the Googles implies it must work for some people (Linux users?), but it's definitely not working for me.

I'd also accept `$HOME` (or some variant), but I can't find the right syntax.

Comment: This might be a better fit for SuperUser http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what if you replace `~` with `%USERPROFILE%` (which, I believe is the equivalent to `$HOME` in Windows)?

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I do almost everything in Powershell, so `$HOME` was expanding in my tests. However internally Mercurial wasn't expanding it properly. I had forgotten about `USERPROFILE`.